# When is a morphism of $k$-ringed spaces the morphism induced by pullbacks?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds, ringed-spaces

Let $(X, O_X)$ and $(Y,O_Y)$ be $k$-ringed spaces ($k$ a field), and let $(f,P)$ be a morphism between them. When is the case that $P: (O_Y(U)) \to O_X(f^{-1}(U))$ is given by precomposition with $f$? I  know this is true for affine algebraic varieties, and it was suggested to me that it was true for other spaces too. I would appreciate it if someone could provide a reference. I am especially interested in the case of real or complex manifolds.

By a morphism of $k$ ringed spaces, I mean a continuous map $f$ along with a pullback map taking the sections of $U \subset Y$ to the sections of $f^{-1}(U)$ that commutes with the restriction maps in the appropriate way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true for real and complex manifolds (viewed as locally ringed spaces over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{R})$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{C})$, respectively, with morphisms $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{R})$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{C})$-morphisms of locally ringed spaces). First note that the definition ensures that all the residue fields are either the real or complex field, according as you are in the smooth or holomorphic case. This allows you to view your ring of global sections as actual functions (the value at a point is the image of the section in the residue field at the point). The rest follows ultimately from the fact that the maps on local rings are local homomorphisms (and induce the identity on residue fields).

Note that this is not true, and simply makes no sense, for schemes over general fields (even over an algebraically closed field $k$, you can only view the global sections as $k$-valued functions upon restricting to closed points, which more or less puts you in the classical setting).

Comment: Why are the induced maps on residue fields necessarily identities? Is this something special about $R$ and $C$, or is there something more general going on?

Comment: It's important that the morphisms in your category of morphisms of locally ringed spaces over $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$, where $k$ is either $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$. The local hypothesis imposed on smooth and complex manifolds ensures that each residue field of your space is either $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$, according as you are in the smooth or complex case (more precisely, for each point $x\in X$, there is a canonical map $k\to k(x)$, and the local hypothesis ensures that this is an isomorphism). Now for a morphism $f:X\to Y$ (over $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$), with $f(x)=y$, the map of local rings

Comment: $f_x^\sharp:\mathscr{O}_{Y,y}\to\mathscr{O}_{X,x}$ is a $k$-algebra map, so the induced map of residue fields $k(y)\to k(x)$ is a $k$-algebra map. But the structure maps $k\to k(y)$ and $k\to k(x)$ are both isomorphisms, so this map must be an isomorphism, in fact the identity if we use the aforementioned structure maps to identify the respective residue fields with $k$. This is not special to $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$. It works for locally $k$-analytic manfolds where $k$ is a non-Archimedean field as well. The point is that these kinds of geometric objects over $k$ have no non-$k$-rational

Comment: points, as opposed to schemes or rigid spaces.

Comment: Thanks - I get it. This is where I have to assume that I am working with $k$-ringed spaces / schemes over $Spec k$, not just locally ringed spaces / schemes.

Comment: Well, for schemes, nothing like this is true except in degenerate situations (or when $k$ is algebraically closed, but even then you usually have non-rational points, so you'd have to restrict to closed points). But if you want to interpret manifolds (smooth or complex or whatever) as locally ringed spaces, you definitely want to regard them as a subcategory of the category of locally ringed spaces over $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ (recall that for a locally ringed space $X$, not necessarily a scheme, a morphism of LRS $X\to\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ is the same as a homomorphism $k\to\mathscr{O}_X(X)$).

Comment: Thanks. In response to your original answer: In the smooth or complex case, how does the definition insure that the residue fields are the real numbers or complex numbers respectively? Surely I can have locally R-ringed spaces where some residue fields are C (such as $Spec R[x]$ at the prime $(x^2 + 1)$)...

Comment: As I said, it's not true for schemes. For manifolds, part of the definition (let's say in the complex case for specificity) is that $X$ is a locally ringed space (over $\mathbf{C}$) for which there is an open covering $X=\bigcup_i U_i$ and isomorphisms of LRS (over $\mathbf{C}$) $(U_i,\mathscr{O}_X\vert_{U_i})\simeq(V_i,\mathscr{O}_{\mathbf{C}^{n_i}}\vert_{V_i})$, where the $V_i$ are opens in $\mathbf{C}^{n_i}$ and the sheaf is the usual sheaf of holomorphic functions. For the latter locally ringed spaces, it's easy to see that the residue fields are all $\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: Oh I see. That makes sense. Thanks for your patience - these ideas are pretty new to me.